# help understanding how to graph a function

Tags: graphing-functions

I am having trouble figuring out how to graph this function.
A(t) = 35e<sup>-0.17t</sup>

When I attempted to graph it my calculator did not display anything and I am not sure how to graph it by hand.

Comment: Think of when the function will take on values that are easy to plot as individual points.  If you know the general shape of the graph of an exponential function, then you can use that knowledge to connect (and extrapolate upon) the points that you plotted.

You will need to use approximation for all values $A(t)$ except for $A(0) = 35$, assuming you use integers for $t$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the scale of your calculator when you tried to graph the function needs to be extended (zoom out).

$$A(t) = 35 e^{-0.17t} = \frac {35}{e^{0.17 t}}$$

[image]

Note that as $t \to \infty$, rather quickly, $A(t) \to 0$. In contrast, as $t$ gets smaller (as we move to the left along the "t" axis, $A(t)$ grows exponentially, and as $t \to -\infty$, $A(t) \to + \infty$. To graph manually, graph $A(0) = 35$, take just a few well-chosen positive values of $t$ and note that as those values get larger, $A(t)$ decreases toward zero.  To get more of where the "action" is, test out more negative values of $t$ than positive values.

Comment: Thank you, I thought I was mistyping the formula in to the calculator, when all I had to do was zoom out

Answer (score 1):

$$A(t) = 35e^{-0.17t}$$

- when power of $e$ becomes $0$, $A(t)=35$
- when $t$ progresses in positive direction, power of $e$ keeps on increasing in negative direction and hence value of $\left[e^{(\text{negative power})}\right]$ keeps on diminishing, but it will never become zero! (?)
- when $t$ progresses in negative direction, power of $e$ keeps on increasing in positive direction and hence value of $\left[e^{(\text{positive power})}\right]$ keeps on increasing exponentially

In the following graph red line is for $y=2^x$ and blue line is for $y=2^{-x}$
[image]